# How to center flex items ignoring their margin?

Tags: javascript, css

How to center two flex items when ignoring their margin? In below example `h1` has assymetric margin, and when using `align-items: center` it does not look good. I dont want to put `flex` on `h1` element because I'm using `innerText` of a header inside my Table Of contents and I don't want to add there a shortcut as well.

```css
h1 {
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Ctrl-H</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code.

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Ctrl-H</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: "Try this" followed by a bunch of code isn't very helpful. This doesn't tell the OP what's wrong with their code, how your code works, why your code works, or even *if* your code works. This teaches them nothing beyond how to copy and paste.